# Schema JSON и foreach php

Tags: php, json, schema

I'm trying to make schema micro markup my FAQPage. My questions and answers are typed in the admin panel in the ACF repeater field and displayed on the site using foreach. I thought I could also do it to generate a json schema, but I can't implement it in any way, I'm still learning. Please tell me what's wrong with me

```
<?php
foreach ($faqs as $faq) {
    $faq .= '[';
    $faq .= '"@type" => "Question",';
    $faq .= '"name => "' . $faq['question'] . '",';
    $faq .= '"acceptedAnswer" => [';
    $faq .= '"@type => Answer",';
    $faq .= '"text => "' . $faq['answer'] . '",';
    $faq .= '],';
    $faq .= ']';
}

$data = [
    '@context' => '//schema.org',
    '@type' => 'FAQPage',
    'mainEntity' => [
        print_r($faq)
    ],
];

$data = json_encode($data);

echo '<script type="application/ld+json">' . $data . '</script>';
?>
```

`$faq['question']` and `$faq['answer']` contain a question and answer.

The result I expect:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "FAQPage",
  "mainEntity": [{
    "@type": "Question",
    "name": "Question #1",
    "acceptedAnswer": {
      "@type": "Answer",
      "text": "Answer #1"
    }
  },{
    "@type": "Question",
    "name": "Question #2",
    "acceptedAnswer": {
      "@type": "Answer",
      "text": "Answer #2"
    }
  }]
}
</script>
```

Comment: Don't try to construct a JSON file yourself. There's `json_encode()` to do the job for you. Exactly how you'd use it here is difficult to say - post the source data and the result you're aiming for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have completed my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to manually build JSON, you can use `json_encode()`:

```
$faqs = [
    ['question' => 'What is the meaning of life?', 'answer' => '42'],
    ['question' => 'What is better, Star Wars or Star Trek?', 'answer' => 'Unable to answer'],
    ['question' => 'What is 1+1', 'answer' => '2, 11, window']
];

function schema_faq($faq)
{
    return [
        '@type' => 'Question',
        'name' => $faq['question'],
        'acceptedAnswer' => [
            '@type' => 'Answer',
            'text' => $faq['answer']
        ]
    ];
}

$schema_faqs = [];

foreach ($faqs as $faq) {
    $schema_faqs[] = schema_faq($faq);
}


$data = [
    '@context' => '//schema.org',
    '@type' => 'FAQPage',
    'mainEntity' => [
        $schema_faqs
    ],
];

$data = json_encode($data);

echo '<script type="application/ld+json">' . $data . '</script>';
```

Outputs:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">{
    "@context": "\/\/schema.org",
    "@type": "FAQPage",
    "mainEntity": [
        [
            {
                "@type": "Question",
                "name": "What is the meaning of life?",
                "acceptedAnswer": {
                    "@type": "Answer",
                    "text": "42"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "Question",
                "name": "What is better, Star Wars or Star Trek?",
                "acceptedAnswer": {
                    "@type": "Answer",
                    "text": "Unable to answer"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "Question",
                "name": "What is 1+1",
                "acceptedAnswer": {
                    "@type": "Answer",
                    "text": "2, 11, window"
                }
            }
        ]
    ]
}</script>
```